# Media in necessitas QT

Tags: android, qt

I'm completly new to qt so question that i'm going to ask can be funny (but for me it really is not).
In normal C++ code I used this line to generate background:

```
  view.setBackgroundBrush(QPixmap("starstexture.jpg"));
```

But as I try to port my application on android, I don't know where I should put jpg file. 
Looking Forward your Answer - 

Kamil

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a limited set of images (that means, you know the images at compile time rather than let the user add his own images in the application's folder) you could use Qt's resource system.

If you're using QtCreator, you could simply add a new resource file to your project, in which you create a new prefix named `/`, then add your file. It is put into your application during compile time and available under the path `":/starstexture.jpg"`. Note the prefix `":/"`, which stands for Qt's resource system. Also note that such file names only work in Qt classes, of course.

Comment: So should I put it just into folder and add to project, or place in res or sth like that? Examples needed...

Comment: Putting them into another folder is optional but recommended; it keeps your source folder clean. If you put the `.qrc` resource file in the same folder, the folder's name will not appear in the resource paths, since they are relative to the `.qrc` file location. (In other words, a prefix called `/` has its root at the `.qrc` location and if you add files from within that folder, they are available via `:/filename` rather than `:/res/filename` as you might think.)